# Finding default gateway in an openvpn environment in windows

Tags: windows, batch, openvpn, routing

I need to find the default gateway in a openvpn scenario where the route output looks like that:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.49.73.1      10.49.73.24     10
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.2     30
```

So I googled around a bit and a found this script [here](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=47121):

```
@For /f "tokens=3" %%* in (
   'route.exe print ^|findstr "\<0.0.0.0\>"'
   ) Do @Set "DefaultGateway=%%*"

echo %DefaultGateway%
```

This works, but matches both lines in the route output.

But I need to find this line:

```
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.49.73.1      10.49.73.24     10
```

So I tried to modify the findstr parameter like this:

```
findstr "\<0.0.0.0\>.\<0.0.0.0\>"
```

in the expectation that '.' will match for the tab between the columns.
But it doesn't. It will still set DefaultGateway to 10.8.0.1

I couldn't find a clue in [MS documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true) either.
Maybe someone knows the right expression?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
For /f "tokens=3" %%* in (
   'route print ^|findstr "\<0.0.0.0.*0.0.0.0\>"'
   ) Do @Set "DefaultGateway=%%*"

echo %DefaultGateway%
```

And you can check `findstr /?` for more informations.

Comment: Ah thats perfect :-) But I do not understand why. When I wrote "\<0.0.0.0\>.\<0.0.0.0\>" did it make findstr stop looking after the first '\>' ?

Comment: First of all the `.` won't do alone, cause aparently it's not just a single tab in the middle.
Then to be honest, I'm not really sure how the `\<` and `\>` work, it's not really part of the standard implementation of regexs as I know it... It's supposedly "beginning/end of word". So I just played around with it until it worked ;P

Comment: Quite likely the `\<` and `\>` forms are required simply to escape the DOS redirection operators.